# Asp.net Web api delegating hangles as a proxy

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I want to create a basix proxy handler for my XmlHttpRequest operations. I am creating a delegationg handler.

```
public class ProxyHandler : DelegatingHandler
{
    protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var forwardUri = new UriBuilder(request.RequestUri);

        request.RequestUri = forwardUri.Uri;

        var client = new HttpClient();

        var response = await client.SendAsync(request, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseContentRead, cancellationToken);

        return response;
    }
}
```

Config

```
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "Proxy", 
            routeTemplate: "{*path}", 
            handler: HttpClientFactory.CreatePipeline(
                    innerHandler: new HttpClientHandler(), 
                    handlers: new DelegatingHandler[] { new ProxyHandler() }),
            defaults: new { path = RouteParameter.Optional },
            constraints: null
        );
```

I want to forwarding request to target server. For example `http://localhost:1123?path=http://another.web.api/controller`

But throws error:

> System.Net.ProtocolViolationException: Cannot send a content-body with
>   this verb-type.

```
`?path=http://another.web.api/controller` request may be post get or put request.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When forwarding `GET` requests you need to set content to `null` for the request passed to your handler. Update your code to check the request method and `null` the content when performing a `GET`.

```
protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    var path = request.GetQueryNameValuePairs().Select(x => x.Key == "path").FirstOrDefault();

    var forwardUri = new UriBuilder(path);

    request.RequestUri = forwardUri.Uri;

    // Add this if block
    if (request.Method == HttpMethod.Get)
    {
        request.Content = null;
    }

    var client = new HttpClient();

    var response = await client.SendAsync(request, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseContentRead, cancellationToken);

    return response;
}
```

Comment: Updated the code with an example of how to get the path query parameter. You should obviously add your own logic for how you would like to manage the absence of the path parameter.